# Mysql query syntax failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I've been trying to execute this mysql query in my php file however I think there may be a problem with it as I get an error whenever it reaches the code.

Here is the query:

```
"INSERT INTO " . $my_tableName . "(mycolumn, myothercolumn)
values ('myvariable', " . $pass . ");" .
"INSERT INTO " .  $my_othertableName . "(morecolumns) values ('morevalues');"
```

And here is the error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':)' at line 1";i:1;s:978:"#0

Comment: It seems you are trying to execute two sql statement on one line hence the "." between the queries. Secondly put a space after the quote joining the fields - $my_tableName . " (mycolumn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to quote your $pass value:

```
"INSERT INTO " . $my_tableName . "(mycolumn, myothercolumn)
values ('myvariable', '" . $pass . "');" .
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can't execute multiple insert statements separated with a ;.  You need to execute these as separate queries.  This is to prevent injection.  Try running as 2 queries and it should work fine for you.